# Abrir modal con un select

Tags: javascript, html, modal

**Hola** estoy tratando de abrir un modal por medio de un `select` y tengo el siguiente codigo `html`

```
<select id = "numbers" onchange = "myFunction()">
 <option value = "1">1</option>
 <option value = "2">2</option>
 <option value = "3">Click me !</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
 <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
 <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
   <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
      </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
     dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Y la funcion de `javascript` que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
function myFunction() {
var option_value = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
if (option_value == "3") {
    alert("Hai !");
 }
}
```

El problema es que al elegir la opcion 3 pues me muestra un `alert`, lo que busco es mostrar un modal hecho con boostrap, intente poner en vez del `alert` un `$('#myModal').modal('show');` pero al elegir no me salia nada, de que otra manera podria hacerlo?

Gracias.

Comment: y donde esta la declaracion de tu modal en html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te agrego la solucion solo debes modificar el contenido
de tu modal

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var option_value = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
if (option_value == "3") {
  //  alert("Hai !");
   $("#myModal").modal();
 }
}
   

</script>
<select id = "numbers" onchange = "myFunction()">
 <option value = "1">1</option>
 <option value = "2">2</option>
 <option value = "3">Click me !</option>
</select>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->


  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Funciona llamando al modal con el metodo show... verifica si tu modal se encuentra en el mismo documento, o si hay una llamada externa, también seria conveniente que integres jquery a tu proyecto.
Esto funciona

```
   <select class="custom-select" id="test">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

   $("#test").click(function() {
        var option_value = document.getElementById("test").value;
        if (option_value == "3") {
            //alert("Hai !");
         $('#TU_MODAL').modal('show');

         }

    })
```